# does getElementsByTagName() return exact match only?

Tags: javascript

I'm thinking it should return only exact match.

I see something like in source I have to work with:

```
var someArray = someObject.getElementsByTagName("item");
```

Except when I inspect the DOM, I don't see any tags named "items".
There are some css classes '.some_item_details'.

Subsequently I see an error about the element being null, which makes sense to me. What bugs me is that I'm seeing this in production codebase. So I'm thinking, "surely no one would commit something like this, I must be missing something".
Wouldn't 'item' have to exist a custom tag?!?

Comment: Indeed, the code snippet you have shown would be searching for `<item>` tags. This might be okay if `someObject` is an XML context.

Comment: Yes, getElementsByTagName matches makes exact matches. So is your question then about custom elements?

Comment: @ Niet the Dark Absol, I think you were first and you did point to the 'real' problem - it is looking for that element in xml from an ajax response. I'd take that as an answer.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: if no probs,I will add your comment in my answer

Answer (score 2):

check [getElementsByTagName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByTagName)

**Indeed**,getElementsByTagName matches makes exact matches.

> Returns an HTMLCollection of elements with the given tag name. The
>   complete document is searched, including the root node. The returned
>   HTMLCollection is live, meaning that it updates itself automatically
>   to stay in sync with the DOM tree without having to call
>   document.getElementsByTagName() again.
>
> **Note**:
>
> document.getElementsByTagName() is similar to
>    element.getElementsByTagName(), except that its search encompasses the
>    whole document.

@NiettheDarkAbsol's comment :

```
var someArray = someObject.getElementsByTagName("item");
```

> Indeed, the code snippet you have shown would be searching for *item*
>   tags. **This might be okay if someObject is an XML context**.